# Teasers in the Sidebar not working via adzerk; why no in-house solution?

Tags: bug, advertising, hot-questions, sidebar

I've been clicking on a teaser in the right sidebar that was something like

```
HOT NETWORK QUESTION - Why is [some korean symbol] associated with [European word]
```

But it only opened an empty page.

The link (shortened) was [http://engine.adzerk.net/r?e=eyJhdiI...](http://engine.adzerk.net/r?e=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&s=Ry5bY4t2yzhp4m3L488p2sNAOvs&url=http%3A%2F%2Fkorean.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F2141%2Fwhy-does-the-name-%25eb%25b0%2595-traditionally-get-romanised-to-park%3Futm_medium%3Dad%26utm_source%3Dhttp-stackoverflow-com-questions-33985147-using-history-mixin-in-es6%26utm_campaign%3Dkorean.stackexchange.com-promo%26utm_content%3D2141)
They have no redirect there.

This is a bug I'd like to report but I also wonder and want to ask:

Why do you not use an inhouse solution, instead of adnetworks like adzerk?

Comment: @CodyGray it's the 'ad' *above* the HNQ list.

Comment: I'm convinced that the Korean characters in the URL of that question aren't handled correctly by Adzerk. Other links *do* work (you can check this by visiting another site where you don't have enough rep to hide most ads).

Comment: We are looking in to this - it is sending us the URL to redirect to but we aren't recognizing it, could definitely be due to the korean characters. We should have it figured out and fixed shortly. (we also aren't an ad network, we are an API focused ad server)

Comment: @JamesAvery Wow, I didn't expect someone would even care. Thank's for your reply and having a look into this. +1 sympathy for AdZerk!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok - this should be resolved now. The issue was that we were unintentionally decoding the redirect URL two times, for the majority of URLs this doesn't cause a problem but for URLs like this it would break the URL.

The URL in the question above should work now.

Apologies from the Adzerk team for the inconvenience.

Comment: +1 for Adzerk - talk about great support.

Comment: Great to hear that even a minor bug is getting perfect attention from you and your team. Thanks for resolving and best wishes for a good x-mas time.